# How can I send a message through NFC from an Android device to a PN532 reader?

Tags: android, arduino, nfc

Dear StackOverflow users,

I have a PN532 shield and I'm using the Adafruit library to control it through a WeMos D1 microcontroller (which is based on Arduino). I'm trying to send it an NDEF message using Android Beam.

I tried host-based card emulation but my Android device (Galaxy Nexus running 4.4 through CMod) doesn't support it. I also checked if I could switch the PN532 to run in card emulation mode, but the Adafruit library doesn't implement this feature on the software side. Reading NDEF from a Mifare classic card works, but when I try to send an NDEF message through this simple code (I took this snippet from the Android dev site) nothing happens.

```
NdefMessage n = new NdefMessage(
            new NdefRecord []{
                    NdefRecord.createMime("text/plain", s.getBytes())
            }
    );

    nfc.setNdefPushMessage(n, this);
```

Just to be safe, I'll also include the Arduino code that receives NFC messages on the other side. It's taken from a library example:

```
if (nfc.readPassiveTargetID(PN532_MIFARE_ISO14443A, uid, &uidlen))
{
Serial.println("Found card!!!");
Serial.println("UID:");
nfc.PrintHex(uid, uidlen);
Serial.println("");
}
```

Am I doing this wrong or is this just not a feasible idea? Thank you advance for your answers